# Converting CSV File To Mysql Database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, csv

I have a php function I wrote in Wordpress. I am taking a CSV file in the same folder as my plugin function and trying to enter it to the database.

I have error reporting enabled in wp-config.php 
as well as with my own php

I get one error messages.

```
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'wuno_inventory' already exists
```

My code does drop the table and creates it. Tested both separately and together. Once I get to the importing the csv file part nothing happens.

So my code is being read but evidently not executing.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

```
function productsExec() {
      $hostname='localhost';
      $username='username';
      $password='password';
      $database='databaseName';
      $table_name = "wuno_inventory";
      // path where your CSV file is located
      define('CSV_PATH','');
      // Name of your CSV file
      $csv_file = CSV_PATH . "inventory.csv"; 

      try {
      $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database",$username,$password);
      $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
      $sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name";
      $dbh->query($sql);

      $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
      id int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      wuno_product varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      wuno_description varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      wuno_alternates varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      wuno_onhand varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      wuno_condition varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;";
      $dbh->query($sql);

    if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
           fgetcsv($handle);   
           while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $num = count($data);
                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                  $col[$c] = $data[$c];
                }

         $col1 = $col[0];
         $col2 = $col[1];
         $col3 = $col[2];
         $col4 = $col[3];
         $col5 = $col[4];

        // SQL Query to insert data into DataBase
        $query = "INSERT INTO " . $table_name . "(wuno_product, wuno_description, wuno_alternates, wuno_onhand, wuno_condition) 
        VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."','".$col5."')";
        $results = $dbh->query( $query );
        }
        fclose($handle);
        }
        if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
        }
        else{
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Data not successfully Inserted.');</script>";
        }
        $dbh = null;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }  
 }
```

csv file

```
Product,Description,Alternates,Onhand,Condition
8855K5,,MS21026-B211,12,12
M39029/5-117,,,13,13
Q4559,,PROD CODE: 40579,1,1
,,40579,,
RESTOCKING CHARGE,,,1,1
TAS8732-1C2,,,7,7
TEST REPORTS,,,6,6
```

And the excel version
[image]

Comment: Are you actually calling your function from anywhere? I see the function definition but not the actual call to the function.

Comment: So you're saying you've confirmed everything else works except the drop table?

Comment: Yes I am calling the function. It even prints out the string at the end of the function telling me everything has been entered to the DB but it has not. And no it is not working. Nothing in the function works. When there is an error bad file path etc it tells me then I fix it then it shows the string at the end of the function I echo but no success.

Comment: How is this a duplicate? That guy is trying to drop a table I am adding a CSV file to a database.

Comment: You're also dropping a table :). But that may not be the issue, granted.

Comment: Actually you were partially correct. The reason it was not dropping the table when I was testing it was because I had it commented out at that point. So that does indeed show that my code is working and runnin through. But it does not add the file to the db

Answer (score 0):

I take it from your commented out code that you've tried `wpdb->query($sql);` ??

EDIT:

Add a semicolon to the end of your $sql query string :)

```
$sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name;"; // see the ; inside the quotes
```

And

```
$query = "INSERT INTO " . $table_name . " (wuno_product, wuno_description, wuno_alternates, wuno_onhand, wuno_condition) 
VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."','".$col5."');";
```

// added the 3rd from the last character: ; inside the quotes, and space before '('

Finally, $col4 and $col5 are undefined as far as I can tell, so that would probably result in the whole query not working.

Comment: Yes as you see in my commented out code I have tried that.

Comment: Please only make one answer. Also please show an example of your answer I am not see what your talking about. You can edit it.

Comment: okay, didn't know that was the preferred etiquette. Everything is in this answer now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This does not fix the problem. sigh This is killing me.

Comment: Can you post example of the csv file contents?

Comment: I did just figure something out. When I consol.log out after each line going down the file it works till i do it after the if(($handle where I am using fopen to get the csv file. So it has to be somewhere after that which is breaking it.

Comment: I edited the question with the information you requested. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Oh, that does help. The console.log info. I think the result of '($handle = fopen(...))' is always going to be false. Try this instead: $handle = fopen(...);    If ($handle) { ...

Comment: I am sorry bro its a little confusing me. Would you mind editing your answer with what you mean so I can just copy and paste what you're talking about

Comment: Never mind, I tested similar code and it returns true. Heading off to bed now.

Comment: Man it has to be something about the way I am handling the file.

Comment: Might have to do some encoding on the input to your sql query.

Comment: you mean maybe I need to escape some of the values? Could we write it so even if the values in the file have chars that need to be escaped we can just do it without knowing when and where they are

Comment: Right, like this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php , although I don't see any chars that need escaping when I compare to those in the escaped chars list.

Comment: Man... I got this to work on my localhost. Then I went back to wordpress and it wouldnt. So I wrote the mysql inserts with pdo instead and now it keeps telling me the table exist. So I deleted the $wpdb->query($sql); after the create table so it just did it all at once after the file opens and it tells me it works now but nothing appears in the database. But like I said it does work on my localhost. Also a problem was there was no space after the INTO" . $tableName changed to  INTO " . $tableName which is what got it to work on my localhost.

Comment: The way my code is now I keep getting this error SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'wuno_inventory' already exists I am going to edit my question so you can see my new code. This works even with the error on localhost but not in wordpress. I think this is the last problem

Comment: Good catch on the missing space. Caused me to notice there's no space after $tableName, too (see revised answer). Also still no ; on the drop query and the last query.

Comment: I took that away and built my own sql statements with PDO. so now I am using dbh because I think the built in WP functions only allow certain privileges with certain functions. Which is annoying and I know for sure what I am doing workd cause it works on my localhost. Are you sure this does not look right, I strongly disagree with where your sticking those ; 
$sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " . $table_name;

Comment: It is a string with an appended variable. the variable should be outside the " "

Comment: Now I am getting this on the insert statement Notice: Undefined variable: sql in wp-content/plugins/wuno-uploader/wuno-uploader.php on line 74
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty Why would sql not be getting set... but it works on local host. I even changed the permissions on the csv file

Comment: I got it... I fixed. For some weird reason in Wordpress I had to use the full file path. Even though the file was in the same directory and it knows it is in the same dir it still made me use a full file path to let it know where it is... thank God this was a pain.